# How to maintain the form showed after clicking a Dialog result in MsgBox?

Tags: vb.net, dialog, event-handling

What I want is the same as cancelling an eventhandler.

In my code,

```
Private Sub btnADD_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnADD.Click

    Dim dlg As New frmGraphDataSelector(m_nCategory, m_sItemSource)

    If dlg.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        ADD(dlg.Setting)
    End If

End Sub
```

I make dlg to set graph options like xaxis,yaxis, unit, etc..

when i click ok button, option settings are saved and add to graph, but one option(divided unit num)can't be zero, so i check it before save option setting.

```
    Private Sub btnOK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click

    If txt_weightandvolume.Text = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Can't divide by 0")
    Else
        GetValueFromUI()
    End If
End Sub
```

In this code, case 0(when input num is zero) error msg showed up and dlg is gone because the ok button worked.
i want in case 0, error msg pop-up and setting dlg keep alive to receive right setting number. how should i change my code?

Comment: in code, 1st code is in frmmain,main UI.  2nd code in option setting class see in 'frmGraphDataSelector'

Comment: Is the OK Button `DialogResult` property set? If so, set it to `none` (the same for the Form's `AcceptButton` property) and *manually* set the `Form.DialogResult` property to `DialogResult.OK` when the validation is completed, before closing it.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you want to maintain the form showed up after clicking the ok button. Then this might it be.

```
Private Sub btnOK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click

If txt_weightandvolume.Text = 0 Then
    MsgBox("Can't divide by 0")
   dim dlg_new as New frmGraphDataSelector(m_nCategory, m_sItemSource)
   if MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
   ADD(dlg_new.Setting)
  End If
Else
    GetValueFromUI()
End If

End Sub
```

Please reply if this helps. Thank you :)

Comment: as i comment in main, in code, 1st code is in frmmain,main UI. 2nd code in option setting class see in 'frmGraphDataSelector'. i can't use showDialog() in subfram(frmGraphDataSelector) i think it's like Self-reference

Comment: Then declare a new variable that would handle also the form and its properties. put it inside your condition.

Comment: @AlexAbulencia `txt_weightandvolume.Text = 0` This cannot compile because the .Text property is a string and 0 is a number. Assuming Option Strict on which it should be.

Comment: That's true, but you can convert the textbox value to integer. also that is not the author wants to know. he wanted to showed the form if he clicks ok in msgbox.